# PHP-style web development on Ruby: creating microframework for that

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, ruby, frameworks

In PHP world you can just create `index.php` file, put some inline code and raw HTML, run Apache and it just works.

> There are a lot af talks about bad practices of using inline code an so on. So we won't discuss this theme here, please.

How can I start my Ruby application same way? I want to use `ERB` for code messing, so it will look this way

```
# index.rb
<h1>Hello world!</h1>
<div>
  1 + 1 = <%= 1 + 1 %>
</div>
```

So my questions are:

1. What makes PHP just work.
   AFAIU(nderstand) There is native support for HTTP in PHP, so I have to use [Rack](http://rack.rubyforge.org/) to support it with Ruby
2. Some basic knowledge for creating my on "microframework": working with application/http servers (Mongrel, nginx, binding on http port and all such kind of job), working with HTTP requests: sessions, params, GET/POST etc (Rack?), sending responses (ERB templating).

So I can make my own (in educational puprposes) microframework for PHP-style web development with Ruby :D

**UPD**

What really I want to do is an application wich will just get request url, run just that file and return HTML  as a response. Also this application should be allowed to be binded on some port

```
index.rb
info/about.rb
info/contacts.rb
products/product.rb
```

so It should parse url `localhost/index.rb` and run `index.rb`, `localhost/products/product.rb?product_id=10` and run `products/product.rb` and pass `product_id=10` as a params hash.

**UPD 2**

I think good point to start is to dig into `Camping` microframework source:

> https://github.com/camping/camping

It is about 5Kb weight so I shouldn't be confused in it

Comment: Why don't you just use Rails or another Ruby based framework? What is it you are trying to do?

Comment: @Mike, because I want to know how it works, how can I make my own, how can I patch it and so on. It is about learning. Of course in production I use Rails, Sinatra, Camping and other cool Ruby frameworks. But I want to not just use them but understand them. And I am trying to do my own microframework wich will work with separate "*.rb" files as pure PHP site do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible to write CGI scripts with Ruby but this is generally not done because we have better solutions.

One file per page is not a very useful abstraction, it's just the one that PHP supports. Ruby has better ways to abstract a web application (like Sinatra, Rails, or even just Rack) so we prefer to use them.

Putting the file name in the url is another unfortunate side effect of PHP's design. It is implementation revealing and unnecessary (you're not getting a Ruby page, you're getting an HTML page), so we choose not to do that either.

CGI and FCGI in Ruby are also slower than the other solutions. This is not because of some limit on how performant they can be; it's mostly just because the effort to make Ruby web applications faster has been spent in more useful areas like Rack and Rails. No one really uses CGI so no one really cares to make it fast. mod_ruby makes CGI scripts somewhat faster if you really want to go this route, but again: there are better ways.

Comment: Thanks, @Rein, but it is not about good and bad, white and black, it is about howto. I understand all those side-effects and I know all those greate frameworks and I use them in my work. But I need to understand it from inside by writing my own dummy microframework. It can be small and with those side effects but it isn't importaint now: it is education, you know

Comment: CGI scripts are not a microframework. They are just an ad-hoc collection of CGI scripts. There is nothing "framework" about that. If you want to learn how to do something, why not learn the best way?

Comment: This is like training yourself to use an abacus. Sure, the abacus was a great calculating tool at one point, but we have better ones now.

Comment: No, you dodn't understand me. I am not just about CGI. I am about how to make it with Ruby. I can use CGI, or Rack or whatever. But I have got a goal and I need a start point.

Comment: Then I think you would be better served using an actual microframework like Sinatra.

Comment: It is not about CGI that I want to do the way it works. My main problem now is to understand how to handle request and how to make my application work with web/application servers

Comment: So if I want to do my own Sinatra but lighter without 80% of its functionality (then I'll get Camping :) actually)

Comment: Sinatra without 80% of its functionality wouldn't be able to do much of anything. Camping isn't lighter, it's just different (and mostly abandoned and harder to use).

Comment: I know Sinatra and use it for few years but I need something more low level then Sinatra

Comment: I will! :) So Rack is the lowes Ruby level for working with HTTP?

Comment: And than you for discussion. My English don't allow me to make clear my thougths and ideas

Comment: @fl00r No, you could use TCPSocket if you truly want *low level*, but I think Rack is what you really want.

Answer (score 2):

Apache can run PHP by loading in the mod_php module.

I believe to run ruby you will need to have it installed on the server and have mod_ruby loaded into apache. take a look at: http://www.modruby.net/en/

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for [CGI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Gateway_Interface). The Apache modules like `mod_php` or `mod_ruby` are just packaging provided for CGI scripts written in PHP or Ruby.

Comment: No, `mod_php` does not just wrap the PHP CGI binary. It's an apache module and works internally different than CGI/FastCGI.