# "PHP Style" development with ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net

I'm learning ASP.NET (slowly), trying to avoid WebForms entirely, but I'm finding MVC, ORMs, EF, and all the rest a little bit overwhelming. I am quite solid with HTML, HTTP, CSS, C# and the BCL.

I have a tiny bit of experience with PHP (ewww), but I've found it to have the deployment and convenience advantages for super small tasks.

I'd like to get a "quick start" where I can just one file in which I can manually connect to the database, run some sql and then loop over the result it to produce some HTML. Small amounts of Visual Studio magic are acceptable. ;)

Is there some sort of microframework or "basic project template" I've been missing?

---

This is similar to [this question about doing the same thing with ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5776339/php-style-web-development-on-ruby-creating-microframework-for-that).

Comment: You can do what you describe in an [ASP.NET MVC](http://www.asp.net/mvc) View (and a whole boatload of other useful stuff in the rest of the framework), without suffering [the madness of PHP.](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/05/php-sucks-but-it-doesnt-matter.html)

Comment: Ok then, what's the best way of having a 'standalone' MVC view?

Comment: Why would you want to do that, when there's so much more happiness using the entire framework?  You can scaffold an entire application in about 5 minutes, if expediency is the issue.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I understand your viewpoint, however:

a) I don't want an entire application. b) It'll only takes 5 minutes *once you know what you're doing*, which I don't. c) It's interesting to know from a educational perspective.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to avoid WebForms all together, then you can use a Handler.

I can understand why you'd want to do this while your learning but remember WebForms are definately not the enemy.

```
<%@ WebHandler Language="C#" Class="MyNamespace.Handler" %>

using System.Web;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace MyNamespace
{
    public class Handler : IHttpHandler
    {

        public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
        {
            context.Response.ContentType = "text/html";
            context.Response.Write("<html><body>");
            string connectionString = ""; // todo: fill in your connection string
            int numThings;
            using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            using (var query = new SqlCommand("select count(*) from Lights", connection))
            {
                numThings = (int)query.ExecuteScalar();
            }
            context.Response.Write("<h1>There are {0} lights!</h1>");
            context.Response.Write("</body></html>");
        }

        public bool IsReusable
        {
            get
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: WebForms are not the enemy? From playing around with the designer all I see are terrible html, a ridiculous number of roundtrips and an insane amount of state[fulness]. I know there are ways to tame most of those things but why? (thanks for answering my perilous question though!)

Answer (score 1):

Check out ASP.NET Web Pages, WebMatrix, and the new Razor syntax, sounds like what you're looking for:

http://www.asp.net/web-pages

I'd highly reccomend learning the MVC framework, but this should be a good start and will be relevant knowledge if/when you decide to go MVC.

Answer (score 1):

If you are too overwhelmed by MVC, EF, etc have a look at ASP.NET Webpages:

- http://www.asp.net/web-pages/tutorials

Its a good starting point and some of the stuff you learnt eg Razor can be applied to ASP.NET MVC